# Unable to pass jinja2 variables into javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

How do i pass jinja2 data into javascript. 
I have a Flask REST url as `/logs/<test_case_name>`
I am trying use `.getJSON()` to query the above URL and hence would want to pass the jinja2 data which has the testcasename to `.getJSON` function.

sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert({{name}});
</script>
```

It doesn't work.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: `{{ name|safe }}` should work

Comment: @JakobBowyer - it dint work :(

Comment: its generally a bad idea to mix template language with javascript. An alternative would be to use html as a proxy - store the name in an element like so <meta id="my-data" data-name="{{name}}" data-other="{{other}}">, then in the javascript do djangoData = $('#my-data').data();

Answer (score 81, accepted):

other than encapsulating the variable in a string, an alternate is jquery for profit:

its generally a bad idea to mix template language with javascript. An alternative would be to use html as a proxy - store the name in an element like so

```
<meta id="my-data" data-name="{{name}}" data-other="{{other}}">
```

then in the javascript do

```
var djangoData = $('#my-data').data();
```

this has advantage in:

- javascript no longer tied to the .html page
- jquery coerces data implicitly

Comment: Thanks @rikAtee. I followed the same logic.. just that i used normal div instead.

Comment: It works but, I think that is a very overkill method - your html file will be  bloated with data attributes, I think the answer below (ndpk's) is a better approach

Comment: Niiiice! Now I can totally isolate *html* from *javacript*. This will allow me a clean integration with Flask-Assets. Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the html syntax corresponds to the original question. Is `data-name` an arbitrary string, or does it have to be `data-name`? Or just start with `data-`? Where has the `other` variable come from?

Comment: @BillCheatham it looks like djangoData is an object with the properties name and other. So you can access the name by using djangoData.name.

Comment: I guess I understand the bad idea thing, but how do I do charts?  I have 50-60 data points to plot.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that you can't give any name to variables inside meta tag, so first I've tried <meta id="geodata" test="{{test}}"> and offcause it don't work. So make variables like this <meta id="geodata" data-test="{{test}}">. It's must be clear from answer, but for some reason it wasn't clear for me at first.

Comment: Here is the option offered from flask.  They recommend using the json filter http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters

`<script type=text/javascript>
    doSomethingWith({{ user.username|tojson|safe }});
</script>`

Comment: It's still not clear what `data-other` is here and what it should be set to.

Comment: .data() returns object. .data("name") returns the value.

Comment: Does this solution works correctly for all situations?
I guess the data may be changed by the user, and this isn't good, as you know.
For example, user can **change** meta element data (without refreshing the page), and if your code runs on some event such as onclick, user can run your javascript code with **wrong data**.

Answer (score 80):

Try with quotes:

```
alert("{{name}}");
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work if `name` contains line breaks such as '\n'. It will throws a javascript syntax error.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is a kinda old topic, but since it attracts a lot of views I suppose some people are still looking for an answer.

Here's the simplest way to do it:

```
var name = {{name|tojson}};
```

It will 'parse' whatever 'name' is and display it correctly:
https://sopython.com/canon/93/render-string-in-jinja-to-javascript-variable/

Comment: Escape secuence for json is equals to javascript but when add a change in json its broken javascript. For better results respect standars: `var name = JSON.parse('{{ name | tojson }}');`.

Answer (score 8):

I just figure I would add the solution I ended up using.

It has a few advantages over the other answers:

- It is 100% valid javascript at the template level (no editor/lint errors).
- Does not need any special HTML tag.
- No dependencies (jquery, or otherwise).

```js
let data = JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson }}');
```

Comment: When using with more complex syntax like `JSON.parse('{{ url_for(\'foo.bar\', filename = \'foobar.txt\') | tojson }}');`, this gives an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1`

Comment: That might very well be a bug then. My understanding is the filter is a wrapper around `json.dumps`, not really sure but I doubt anyone implemented a json encoder for this.

Answer (score 5):

**This is how I did it**

My html Element

```
<!--Proxy Tag for playlist data-->
<meta id="my_playlist_data" data-playlist="{{ playlist }}">
```

My script element

```
// use Jquery to get data from proxy Html element
var playlist_data = $('#my_playlist_data').data("playlist");
```

See [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) documenttation for more

Answer (score 2):

you can try alert({{name|safe}});

Comment: Hi There. Try elaborating or post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

<input type="hidden" name="token_idx" id="token_idx" value='{{token|safe }}'

let token_data = document.getElementById("token_idx").value;

Answer (score 1):

Adding my working solution from HTML as I spent a full day hunting for it in case it helps someone.

This html is passed back its prefill data and I could not get access to the variables I needed from that dict in the Jinja2 for loop

`render_template('home.html', prefill_data=request.form)`

The real key here was this trick to get a variable in as key in string format `prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]`

And these curly braces to access value as string
`"{{ prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]}}"`

```
{% if nplayer_form is not defined %}
    {% set nplayer_form = 4 %}
{% endif %}   

{% if session['additional_players'] %}
    {% set nplayer_form = nplayer_form + session['additional_players'] %}
{% endif %}


{% for i in range(nplayer_form) %}
    {% set n = i+1 %}

<tr id="Row{{ n }}">
<td>
<label for="player{{ n }}name_input" name="player{{ n }}name_input_label"></label>
<input type="text" name="player{{n}}name" id = "player{{n}}name_input" {% if prefill_data %} value="{{ prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]}}"{% endif %}/>
</td>

<td>
<label for="player{{n}}strength_id" name="player{{n}}strength"></label>
<select name="player{{n}}strength" id="player{{n}}strength_id"> 
    <option value="1" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "1") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Beginner</option>
    <option value="2" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "2") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Intermediate</option>
    <option value="3" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "3") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Advanced</option>                 
</select>
</td>

<td>
<label for="p{{n}}checkbox_id" name="p{{n}}checkbox_label">
<input type="checkbox" id="p{{n}}checkbox_id" name="p{{n}}checkbox" {% if prefill_data %} {% if (prefill_data["p{}checkbox".format(n)] =="on") %} checked {% endif %} {% endif %} />
</label>
</td>

</tr>
```