# How to pass Java String value or list of strings to javascript using JINJAVA

Tags: javascript, java, jinjava

We can access java values passed through JINJAVA in HTML using {{}}. How can we access the same in javascript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626048/unable-to-pass-jinja2-variables-into-javascript-snippet[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626048/unable-to-pass-jinja2-variables-into-javascript-snippet%5BSimilar) thing can be done here too like the accepted answer for this question]